# I sent a pair of solana tokens to a Solana program address

Tags: token

I would appreciate if you could help me. By mistake I
sent a pair of solana tokens (28) to the Solana program address for
the BSC network BNB Smart Chain (BEP20). I have all the background.
Please tell me who I can solve it with, I have tried to find someone
and it has been impossible. Best regards.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the mistake, but there's no one who can help you here unfortunately. It sounds like this is a BSC problem, and if it were on the Solana network, you would need to coordinate with the recipient of the funds to retrieve them.